# Integral involving Bessel function $J_0$.

Tags: improper-integrals, bessel-functions

Is there a closed form solution to 
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty \frac{J_0(kr)}{k}dk,
\end{equation}
where $J_0$ is Bessel function and $r$ is a constant?

Comment: Your integral is not convergent. You have, essentially a $1/k$ as $k\to0^+$.

Comment: I got this integral while I was trying to find inverse Fourier transform of $1/k^2$ in two dimensions. Was expecting to get a logarithm, something like $\ln r$.

Comment: The general solution can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1213371).

Comment: The integral is indeed divergent. If that helps, though $$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\left[\ln\epsilon+\int_{\epsilon}^\infty dk\frac{J_0(kr)}{k}\right]=\ln \left(\frac{2}{r}\right)-\gamma\ ,$$
where $\gamma$ is the Euler's constant.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments. The problem of finding inverse Fourier transform of $1/k^2$ is briefly discussed at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/847706/does-the-integral-in-the-formal-2d-fourier-transform-of-the-logarithm-converge.